# The problem when I calculate the limit of function with trigonometric contant in MATLAB（Android）

Tags: matlab, limit

I get the wrong answer when I input these code in Android MATLAB：

syms x

limit((sin(x)-sin(1))/(x-1),x,1)

it returned NaN but it should be cos(1) in math,but my MATLAB in Android didn't throw any warning or exception.

I dont't learn well how to use MATLAB so that I cannot figure out whether my code is wrong or my MATLAB in Andriod didn't work properly.(I cannot use MATLAB in pc recently)

If it is the former,please tell me why it's wrong and what should I do to fix it.

My English level just like my MATLAB level and this is my first time to ask question in this website.I'm sorry if I have any mistake in politeness or norm.

Comment: Maybe that should have been 1 degree, rather than 1 radian?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, the result is `NaN`, and that's also the case for desktop editions of matlab. It's one of the perils of mixing numeric and symbolic computation, the way matlab does.

The problem is that matlab doesn't know to evaluate `sin(1)` as a symbolic expression - by default it evaluates everything as numeric, using double precision floating point. So it evaluates the subexpression `sin(1)` to an imprecise (64 bit) floating value, before being able to employ symbolic algorithms to compute the limit, which should be `cos(1)`.

Thus, at `x = 1`, `sin(x) - sin(1)` is not exactly zero - the subexpression `sin(x)` gets the symbolic treatment and is evaluated at `x = 1` as the exact real number sin 1, while the subexpression `sin(1)` is just an approximation (albeit an excellent one for almost all practical uses), but not exactly the real number.

**The solution** is to write `sin(sym(1))` instead of `sin(1)`, so the second term gets also treated as a symbolic expression:

```matlab
syms x

limit((sin(x)-sin(sym(1)))/(x-1), x, 1)  % cos(1)
```

You may find more details in the [Choose Numeric or Symbolic Arithmetic](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/choose-symbolic-or-numeric-arithmetic.html) chapter in the docs.

With that explanation, it's still interesting why the result was `NaN` and not infinite. That's actually the symbolic computation part doing its job: since `sin(x)-sin(1)` is not perfectly zero at `x=1`, the expression doesn't have a limit, since only `x-1` changes the sign at `x=1`:

```matlab
limit((sin(x)-sin(1))/(x-1), x, 1, 'left') % -Inf
limit((sin(x)-sin(1))/(x-1), x, 1, 'right') % +Inf
```

Comment: The problem has been solved. Thank you very much for your patient and meticulous explanation